# Twitter API. Получить все ответы твита

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-api

Как можно получить все ответы на определенный твит в Twitter api 1.1
В документации искал ничего не нашел. В Гугле все неоднозначно, некоторые делают это в несколько шагов. Какие есть вобще способы ?

Answer (score 1):

Раньше был related_results, но сейчас его нет.

related_results will not be appearing in API v1.1.

А еще они писали так

> The best way to obtain the different aspects of a conversation is by monitoring a user using the Streaming API, User Streams, or Site Streams as they happen.

Как вариант, раньше точно можно было через поиск [q="to:$username", sinceId = $tweetId]
А потом обойти и найти записи где in_reply_to_status_id_str = $tweetId